# Plugin widget zindex changes depending on theme

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin that has a widget option.

The widget pops a screen with a petition form.

The problem is that the way the widget pops seems to depend on the theme.  The site is https://speakout.123host.net.au with the widget at the bottom of the left column.

Using the TwentyFifteen theme (currently active) when scrolled to either the top or the bottom the `<article>` element jumps to the front.  But scroll away from either extreme and the page looks as expected with the widget in front.

Using the TwentySeventeen theme it works perfectly with the widget in front.

A user has reported that another (unknown) theme has the `<article>` element in front all the time.

The z-index is set way high for the popup.  Is there a way to ensure the pop up is always at the front?

Comment: This is a general CSS problem, not a WP problem